# List of complex refractive indices for various frequencies and various materials

Tags: optics, resource-recommendations, dielectric, absorption, metamaterials

I want a list of refractive index values for various materials (or even a single material) for various frequencies / wavelengths (I need this specifically for the micro wave - radio wave regions of the spectrum). I have searched the internet for the same but have found none. Can anybody tell me where I can find such a table of values? I am looking at materials such as lossy materials, gain materials, meta materials, etc.

Comment: You can start here : https://refractiveindex.info/

Comment: This is great but it doesn't provide the values in the range of microwaves and radio waves which is the range that I require.

Comment: You didn't even bother to specify that in your post.

Comment: https://www.fig.net/resources/proceedings/fig_proceedings/fig_2002/Js28/JS28_rueger.pdf